# Kicking NaN out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, nan

I am having trouble kicking NaN out of array "free_time_integers" below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>parse testing</title>
</head>
<body>

<textarea name="" id="txt1" cols="30" rows="10">
1139
2938
3828
112
</textarea>


<script>

  var free_time_hours = document.getElementById('txt1')
//  free_time_hours.addEventListener("blur", free_time_console)

  // Parse the free time values into times

  // convert textarea into array
  var breaker_array = free_time_hours.value.split(/\n/)
  console.log("array freshly split")
  console.log(breaker_array)

    //convert array each element to a string

  let free_time_integers = breaker_array.map(function(obj) {
    return parseInt(obj)
  })

  // get the NaN out of the array
  
  function remove_false(arr) {
    arr.filter(Boolean)
  }

  remove_false(free_time_integers)

  console.log("after map-parseInt and filter-true")
  console.log(free_time_integers)

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried using a for loop and if statement to check if any item === NaN but that didn't seem to work either. I read in another thread that NaN doesn't equal itself so that may be why. Is there any way to eliminate the NaN values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isNaN` to check if it something a NaN and the Array.filter function to keep the elements that is not NaN. Another issue is that you have to store the results somewhere. So, your final code will look like the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>parse testing</title>
</head>
<body>

<textarea name="" id="txt1" cols="30" rows="10">
1139
2938
3828
112
</textarea>


<script>

  var free_time_hours = document.getElementById('txt1')
//  free_time_hours.addEventListener("blur", free_time_console)

  // Parse the free time values into times

  // convert textarea into array
  var breaker_array = free_time_hours.value.split(/\n/)
  console.log("array freshly split")
  console.log(breaker_array)

    //convert array each element to a string

  let free_time_integers = breaker_array.map(function(obj) {
    return parseInt(obj)
  })

  // get the NaN out of the array
  // my implementation here...
  function remove_false(arr) {
    return arr.filter(e => !isNaN(e));
  }
  
  // assign it to a variable
  var filtered_arr = remove_false(free_time_integers)

  console.log("after map-parseInt and filter-true")
  console.log(filtered_arr)

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`filter` returns a new array, you need to reassign it to `free_time_integers`

```
  function remove_false(arr) {
    return arr.filter(Boolean)
  }

  free_time_integers = remove_false(free_time_integers)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>parse testing</title>
</head>
<body>

<textarea name="" id="txt1" cols="30" rows="10">
1139
2938
3828
112
</textarea>


<script>

  var free_time_hours = document.getElementById('txt1')
//  free_time_hours.addEventListener("blur", free_time_console)

  // Parse the free time values into times

  // convert textarea into array
  var breaker_array = free_time_hours.value.split(/\n/)
  console.log("array freshly split")
  console.log(breaker_array)

    //convert array each element to a string

  let free_time_integers = breaker_array.map(function(obj) {
    return parseInt(obj)
  })

  // get the NaN out of the array
  
  function remove_false(arr) {
    return arr.filter(Boolean)
  }

  free_time_integers = remove_false(free_time_integers)

  console.log("after map-parseInt and filter-true")
  console.log(free_time_integers)

</script>


</body>
</html>
```